# Best Practice CSS to refacing/redesigning a large website

Tags: css

I am currently redesigning a large e-commerce website. I have the entire website on my local, so however I decided to approach the redesign (CSS and HTML) changes won't affect the live site. I have never actually refaced an existing website. Typically, I am building a website from scratch. My question is this: What is the best way to tackle a  complete refacing of a website? The current website CSS is not bad, although it is vastly different than my own style. Should I just start from scratch on the CSS or try to modify the existing? What are the best practices for doing this type of thing? Any advice would help? Like everything time is an issue..

Thanks,
DH

Comment: Is the just "skin" changing or is the layout/placement changing as well?

Comment: I think it depends on how different the new design is.  If it's completely different then starting from scratch would probably be easier.  You're either going to put in a lot of time getting familiar with the existing CSS or creating new CSS.  Either way, starting from scratch would probably take more time but it might save you time in the long run if you'll be doing the maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got the time you should go for a redesign. you can use the existing site as a reference for content / materials, and maybe even reuse some of the appropriate styles.

In my experience in just about everything (HTML, JAVASCRIPT, C#, SQL, etc..) If you start changing the existing "code / css" you'll find yourself hours into the project only to realize that you should've just re-done it..

basically, if you try to do something that the original author never intended, you'll end up forcing in new code.. and when you're all done, you may realize that 90% of the changes are actually new / added code, so in the end, you may realize that you've ended up leveraging 10% of existing, and instead of integrating that 10% into the new design, you've frankenstiened in 90% of the new code..

Answer (score 1):

Start from scratch - one step at a time. You can't start from zero on a large live sites. Take baby-steps and redesign as you go.

1) Get rid of the awful stuff: If you have inline styles, tables used for layout or a bad case of DIV-itis, clean these up first. You also have to consider interactivity - are things you're changing hooked up to JavaScript event handlers? Will doing this break anything?

2) Consolidate and test: merge stylesheets, JS and other elements to maintain cleaner code. Test to ensure the site still works as expected.

3) Break the rest into chunks and re-work as you go. Eventually you can make it "all yours" through careful planning and a bit of TLC.